# Powerpivot Odata feed provide credentials

Tags: c#, excel, wcf, odata, excel-2013

I created a OData web services which are hosted in a secure server, to access these services, user need to provide credentials which then gets authenticated using cookie (TMG Fore Front Server Forms)

How can I provide credentials to `Table Import Wizard` > `Connect to a Data Feed` ?

As I get 401 when I enter svc and do test connection.

**Update**

Quiet weird but it was giving me 401 if button clicked after putting url into it, but now I tried from start again, instead of adding url, clicked on advance button and this is what I can see now,

[image]

now if I add password and userid, I get this error,

```
============================
Error Message:
============================

The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

============================
Call Stack:
============================

   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Common.DataSourceBasic.UpdateDataFeedParametersInternal(ConnectionStringBuilder connBuilder, IDataSource dataSource, Boolean checkFeedValid, Boolean fKeepAlive)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Common.DataSourceBasic.UpdateDataFeedParameters(ConnectionStringBuilder connBuilder, IDataSource dataSource, Boolean checkFeedValid)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Common.DataSourceBasic.GetCurrentConnectionString(Boolean checkFeedValid)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Common.DataSourceBasic.ClickTestConnection(Object progressControl)
```

Comment: Which version of OData?

Comment: @wadry V3, but I am not sure if it will change anything though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since I happen to know this is a sharepoint based solution you have been working on I think this should be relevant ...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210671(v=sql.120).aspx

... and for power pivot add on in excel ...

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Connect-to-an-OData-feed-Power-Query-4441a94d-9392-488a-a6a9-739b6d2ad500

... clicking on the option "from odata feed" in that menu gives you options to build a query, you can also specify the credentials.

Setting up the query gives you the ability to do this ...

https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2014/03/26/working-with-web-services-in-power-query/